# planner_frequency not working once robot stands still

Tags: ros, global-planner

I have written my own global_planner_plugin for ROS which tries to map an initially unknown area. The "goal" variable sent to the makePlan method is therefore unused. As to not have too long computational time before my robot start moving, I only plan 10 steps into the future and use the travel time to compute the next 10 points and so on. I want my robot to update its global plan not with a timer as in planner_frequency but rather when the current path is done (but the "goal" is not reached. It is placed far away just to get to robot going.)

Right not, I use a different solution where I set planner_frequency to 0.1 to give my robot time to travel. I the robot is not finished with its path, replanning works fine, but if it has reached the end of the path and is standing still waiting for the 10 second mark, it never replans.

Is there any solution/method to do what I want and/or is there any way to keep the robot replanning ever after having stood still?

I use TEB_local_planner at 5 Hz as my local planner.